# Like operator and cyrillic symbols with MySQL and jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc, utf-8, sql-like

Why all is going like this? http://cs621724.vk.me/v621724427/19ade/rqgKgpzZPbU.jpg

```
create table b(tt varchar(2));
insert into b select 'ы ';
SELECT * FROM allservices.b;
```

result from Workbench is
    # tt
    'ы'
But with jdbc...

```
        connection = initConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareCall("select tt from b where tt like '%ы%'");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("----------");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("tt"));
        }
        System.out.println("==========");
        statement = connection.prepareCall("select tt from b where tt like '%'");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("----------");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("tt"));
        }
        System.out.println("==========");
```

result is: 
     ----------
     ==========
     ----------
     ы 
     ==========

Answer (score 1):

```
set names utf8;  -- To say your client is using utf8 encoding
create table b(tt varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8);  -- to say the column is utf8
```

When you get it inserted, do this:

```
mysql> select hex(tt) from b;
+---------+
| hex(tt) |
+---------+
| D18B20  |  -- You should see this.  D18B is the yery ('ы') character; 20 is space. 
+---------+
```

Comment: no, result is same. All my other tables created with character set utf8.  create table bb(tt varchar(2) character set utf8);
 insert into bb select 'ы ';
     ... statement = connection.prepareCall("select tt from b where tt like '%ы%'");--------------- ========== and 'D18B20'
for hex.

Comment: Let's see the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE bb` -- I'm looking for a charset or collation that is not what you expect.  And, can you determine what settings jdbc is running with?

Comment: 'CREATE TABLE `bb` (\n  `tt` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'. JDBC is running as usual (MySQL driver registration, connection etc.).

Comment: Do your JDBC connection parameters include `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8`?

Comment: I am using them like this jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/allServices?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8, but... problem still exists.

Comment: Even "select * from service where service like '%Б%' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci limit 1" from my other tables does not help.